# ".ssh/config" E212: Can not open file for writing

Tags: linux, vim, ssh

I'm new to linux. I downloaded an image of ubuntu 12 for VirtualBox and I want to configure the `.ssh/config` file to access via ssh to an application in development.

I access `/home/ubuntu` folder and I login as root, I type `vim .ssh/config` and when I save I get the error: `.ssh/config` E212: Can not open file for writing.
Y saved it with :w, :w!, :wq! and I can´t.

I tried with `sudo .ssh/config` and `sudo ~/.ssh/config`.

I've tried different virtual machines so i don't know can be causing this error. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Open your editor as root user.

Comment: Are you trying to configure the `~/.ssh/config`? If so, you should't need to be root.

Answer (score 6):

If the .ssh folder didn't exist you could get this.

In which case you could create it first with:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

When using vi on files with elevated permissions you have to use `sudo`

For example you must use `sudo vi .ssh/config`

This is because the .ssh directory or the .ssh/config file must be owned by root and when using the sudo command it elevates your privileges to root for the duration of that process.

Comment: Yes, I tried it too... but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can be probably in read mounted filesystem though you can try the following steps For some reason the file you are writing to cannot be created or overwritten.
The reason could be that you do not have permission to write in the directory
or the file name is not valid.

Vim has a builtin help system, I just quoted what it says to :h E212. You might want to edit the file as a superuser like sudo vim FILE. Or if you don't want to leave your existing vim session (and know have proper sudo rights), you can issue:

:w !sudo tee % > /dev/null
Which will save the file. I found this on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253362/etc-apt-sources-list-e212-cant-open-file-for-writing

Thanks & Regards,
Alok

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I still have problem to save it. I typed that and this is the output:


`:w !sudo tee % > /dev/null`
`tee: .ssh/config: No such file or directory`

`shell returned 1`

How can I know if the image is for readonly ? ¿Can someone link a image without this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Go to
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\user.ssh
and make sure you can't see any config file with the windows explorer, in my case there was already one config file, which i was not able to see it via ubuntu terminal